# Suppress indirect leaks caused by third party libraries

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer, guile

I have this very simple `C` code calling a `scheme` script with `guile`:

```
/* main.c */
#include <libguile.h>

int main(void)
{
    scm_init_guile();
    scm_c_primitive_load("script.scm");

    SCM func = scm_variable_ref(scm_c_lookup("func"));

    scm_call_0(func);
    return 0;
}
```

The `scheme` script:

```
; script.scm
(define (func)
    (display "Hello from scheme\n")
)
```

Compiling and running with:

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=asan.supp
gcc -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall `pkg-config --cflags guile-3.0` \
    -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer \
    -o demo main.c `pkg-config --libs guile-3.0`
./demo
```

I'm able to suppress some of the leaks caused by `guile` using this suppression file (`asan.supp`):

```
leak:iconv_open
leak:libguile
```

But one of the leaks doesn't provide enough information, the sanitizer output is:

```
=================================================================
==33333==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Indirect leak of 208 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff8a9b8d517 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb0517)
    #1 0x7ff8a97e94f6  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x344f6)

-----------------------------------------------------
Suppressions used:
  count      bytes template
      2      32752 iconv_open
      1         32 libguile
-----------------------------------------------------

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 208 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

As you can see, the information about the leak is very generic (`malloc` and `libc`), of course I can not put `libc` in the suppression file since I will not get information about my real leaks.

Is there any way to suppress all "indirect leaks" caused by third party libraries?

Comment: Are you sure this leak is because of guile? Because I think it's from the executable startup code. What do you get with an empty `main` function?

Comment: Hi @ssbssa, sure, `#include <libguile.h> int main(void) { scm_init_guile(); } ` returns a leak of 32 bytes, including the call to the scheme function returns a leak of 208 bytes

Comment: I mean completely empty, without `scm_init_guile`.

Comment: @ssbssa an empty `main` including `#include <libguile.h>` doesn't return any leak

Comment: Does adding `fast_unwind_on_malloc=0` to your `ASAN_OPTIONS` (or `LSAN_OPTIONS`) help?

Comment: @SamBrightman yes it does, `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1:fast_unwind_on_malloc=0` works like a charm. Thanks a lot!! Please, feel free to add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` - which you do - I believe you need to add `fast_unwind_on_malloc=0` to your `ASAN_OPTIONS` (or `LSAN_OPTIONS`) in some cases. This will be slower but give more complete backtraces.

For C++ `new`/`delete` the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) also suggests switching to `-shared-libstdc++`, which would presumably be faster. That doesn’t seem relevant to you though.